# ¿Por qué no me aparecen algunas carpetas en el localhost del Xampp?

Tags: php, xampp

Tengo instalado *xampp* y en una carpeta hay otras 3, pero si lo abro con `http://localhost` de *xampp* no me las muestra.

¿Alguien sabe a qué se debe esto?

[image: Captura del navegador web]

[image: Captura del explorador de archivos]

Comment: Puede ser un tema de permisos y propietarios. Por ejemplo,  el chown de las carpetas no sea www-data?

Comment: Deberías comprobar si la configuración del `DocumentRoot` del `<VirtualHost>` coincide con la ruta que estás mirando. Para estar seguro crea un `index.php` con el contenido `<?= htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) ?>`, luego fuerza la actualización de la página (el método varía de un navegador a otro) para ver si lo abre o no (se supone que debería usarlo como índice de página) y si muestra la ruta correcta. Si compartes la configuración del servidor Apache y la ruta que estás mostrando en la captura de pantalla podremos intuir algo más.